# How to use python package source code instead of using it after installing

Tags: python

I want to use `psycopg2` for db operations. But as the code will be packaged and sent, I dont have to permission to install it on the remote server where it will be used. Can you please tell how to use the code directly from the `tar.gz` bundle? I have put the path in site-packages, but still getting `ImportError`. Can anyone please tell how to do that for `psycopg2` and for that matter, any python package we want to use directly without installing, just by using the source code?

Comment: have you set the proper path. import sys; sys.path.append(your_path)

Comment: You don't need special permissions when you use a [virtual environment](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for your packages.

Comment: @KarthikBhatK: Yes, I did it via site packages. But the structure inside the downloaded tar is different from the usage mentioned.

Comment: @KlausD.: The local machine we have here doesn't have pip and all installations are blocked. So, that is why looking for a way to directly use the tar bundle.

Answer (score 1):

For most python packages/modules, you should be able to build the module without installing it:

```
python setup.py build
```

and copy the built module/package from `./build` directory and use it. In case of `psycopg2` package, I started with cloning the psycopg repository:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:psycopg/psycopg2.git
```

and then built it:

```sh
cd psycopg2
python setup.py build
```

I then copied the package directory to a new directory where my own code lives:

```sh
cp -a build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2 ~/myproject
```

and imported it:

```sh
cd ~/myproject
python

Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 27 2017, 00:27:06) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20170306] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
```

**Note** that `psycopg2` is a C binding and hence compiled code when built. Therefore the build package runs only on machines with the same architecture as your own.